# Can a magnet repel a ferromagnetic sphere?

Tags: energy, magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

I have to repel a sphere using a magnet for an experiment. But apparently the magnets attract the sphere to the north and south poles instead of (as I expected) to one of the poles. Is there a way to avoid this effect?

Kind regards!

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ferromagnetic object in a non-uniform magnetic field will always feel a force in the direction of increasing magnetic field. If you want it to feel a force in the opposite direction then you will need to change your magnetic field so that it is increasing in the opposite direction.

Diamagnetic materials feel a force in the direction of decreasing magnetic field. However, the force on a diamagnetic material is far smaller than the force on a ferromagnetic object.